# Securly pass Id from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass an id from view to controller without the user being able to change it's value (change URL attributes or by using inspector).

Is storing the Id to TempData the best option?

Comment: Use HTTPS (not HTTP) and put ID into an HTTP Header which is encrypted using HTTPS.

Comment: simply encrypt the `id` using any algorithm(with `key` and `datetime`), if there is any change then mark it as invalid

Comment: @jdweng And how would that prevent a user from changing the value?

Comment: It is compiled into the code. or you put into a config file and normal users can't edit.

Comment: @jdweng That would not prevent a user from changing the value sent to the server. The truth is, you can't prevent a user from changing the value, because you don't have control over the user's machine. You *can* encrypt the value and if you have strong encryption, you can be reasonably sure that the value you're receiving hasn't been tampered with, but you can't actually prevent them from changing the value sent to the server. The client is always in control of their machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypt ID before you render your page and then decrypt it when you retrieve it at controller.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/encryption-and-decryption-using-a-symmetric-key-in-c-sharp/